# Firestore security rules to allow querying documents within maximum gap of 31 days between start and end date

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have documents like this:

```
timesheets (collection)
-- auto_doc_id_1 (document): {
   start_time: yyyy:mm-dd hh:mm:ss
   duration: int

-- auto_doc_id_2 (document): {
   start_time: yyyy:mm-dd hh:mm:ss
   duration: int

....
```

And I query it like:

```
firestore.collection("timesheets")
.where("start_time", ">", start_from)
.where("start_time", "<", start_to)
.orderBy("start_time")
.get();
```

I want to add security rules, where the maximum difference between `start_from` and `start_to` should be less than/equal to 31 days.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in security rules, nor even in a query as it is impossible to use a reference to a field in the value of a condition.

The common way to solve this is to store the interval between the two dates as a separate field. You can then enforce that this interval is the correct value in security rules, and query on that interval field.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to enforce in security rules for each document individually in a query.  You could require the values provided in the query have certain limits relative to each other, but you can't do this for each document separate from each other.

Your only viable option is to instead write the time distance between start and end as its own field in the document, and use that as a filter in both the query and the rules.